# What color is Luke’s lightsaber blade?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, luke-skywalker

I was reading some trivia and came across this question and was surprised by the answer. The answer is blue. However, this is not completely true.

In the *Star Wars Episode IV: New Hope*, Luke is given (by Obi-Wan) a lightsaber with a blue blade. Although this lightsaber belonged to Luke, it was not constructed by Luke. It belonged to his father Anakin Skywalker and was constructed by Anakin. So, this is not Luke’s lightsaber.

In *Return of the Jedi*, Luke has constructed his own lightsaber, and the blade is now green similar to Yoda’s. In the new movie *Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens*, the lightsaber that supposedly belongs to Luke has a blue blade. There is no explanation for this anomaly.

Did Disney get it wrong or was the lightsaber in *Return of the Jedi* supposed to be blue? Did Luke construct a new lightsaber with a blue blade similar to his father’s?

Comment: I don't really think of it as an anomaly. The lightsaber seen in episode VII is indeed the one given to Luke by Obi-Wan. Yes, it wasn't built by him, but for all practical purposes, it belongs to him. Just like if I inherit something after my father's death, it is mine. Or if my father gave me his old car, I would say that it's mine and stop referring to it as his. As for the green saber, I would imagine that it doesn't appear because Luke has it with him.

Comment: @Alarion: "[not] an anomaly (...) indeed the one given to Luke by Obi-Wan" - maybe the question should highlight that [the last time we saw that lightsaber before was when it tumbled away into the endless depths of the chute on Cloud City, along with Luke's severed hand](https://youtu.be/C-DeI3ohVbY?t=319).

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/z74xg5I20mw/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: See [when do we first see Luke's lightsaber?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111503/when-does-lukes-lightsaber-first-appear-in-the-star-wars-saga/111600#111600)

Comment: @Richard: Hmm ... in that graphic, [Mace Windu's lightsaber](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/1/10/Yoda_mace_windu_ki-adi-mundi_battle_of_geonosis.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111116045153) is blue and [Ki-Adi Mundi's lightsaber](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/0/0f/KiAdiMundiGeonosis-LaPR.png/revision/latest?cb=20120831044838) is purple ... they appear to be switched (?)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes, the first two names need to be switched in that graphic

Comment: yes the saber that rey has is luke's first saber.

Comment: This question answers itself on all counts.

Comment: It'd be awesome if Luke's hand was also in a trunk somewhere.

Comment: If someone passes down an item to me that once belonged to my father, it's still mine.  The fact that he made it or it used to be his does not make it not mine.

Comment: @JohnSensebe You mean like it was in the EU continuity?

Answer (score 41):

The blue lightsaber in *The Force Awakens* is Anakin's blue lightsaber and the lightsaber that Luke lost in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

[image: Anakin's lightsaber]

[image: Luke's lightsaber, A New Hope]

[image: Skywalker lightsaber, The Force Awakens trailer]

It is quite different from Luke's newer green lightsaber.

[image: Luke's new lightsaber]

We don't yet know how Anakin's lightsaber was found or retrieved.

([Source](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skywalker%27s_lightsaber))

Comment: Argh! **HOW** given that Anakin's/ObiWan's/Luke's blue lightsaber fell into the depths of the gas giant Bespin?

Comment: @Lexible To quote the answer: "We don't yet know how Anakin's lightsaber was found or retrieved."

Comment: I thought his lightsaber + hand fell down the shaft well before Luke did...

Comment: @RogueJedi Actually we do know, sort of. There is a deleted scene that was removed from the beginning of Episode VII with a lightsaber floating in space in the Bespin system. Originally the scene had a hand in it as well, then the hand was cut (no pun intended) from the scene, and then the whole scene was cut from the film. I don't know what level of canon deleted scenes count as, though.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer to the titular question be: which one? I think both the blue and the green one are "Luke's lightsaber". Your answer thoroughly addresses the questions raised in the question body but, currently, none of the answers address "What color is Luke's lightsaber blade?"

Comment: @Kapler Not sure what you mean. I specified that the RotS/ANH/ESB/TFA saber is blue and the RotJ saber is green.

Comment: @RogueJedi All I'm saying is that the question "What color is Luke's lightsaber blade?" is not directly answered. In fact, you call the blue one Anakin's and the Green one Luke's. I think just adding "Luke had two lightsabers, one was blue and one was green" to the beginning of your answer would satisfy my (maybe pedantic) point.

Comment: @NickT It did - that doesn't necessarily mean that it ended up in the same place as Luke. Luke went through several shafts and hatches before being dumped out the bottom of the city.

Comment: According to legends, Vader went to the garbage disposal areas and found an ugnaught holding it. He requested it be handed to him, but the ugnaught said he'd give it if Vader handed over his helmet. Vader promptly crushed his wind pipe. but thats legends so JJ, got some explaining to do.

Answer (score 36):

It is very easy to get confused, because there are an awful lot of different lightsabers in the *Star Wars* series, and it's difficult to keep track of them all.  Bear with me here...

### Which lightsaber is which?

#### The blue lightsaber

The blue lightsaber that Rey gets is [Luke's FIRST lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_second_lightsaber).

[image: Still from "A New Hope"; Luke and Obi-Wan in Obi-Wan's Tatooine dwelling. Luke is standing centre frame facing the camera, head turned to look at the lit lightsaber in his right hand. Obi-Wan sits to his left, observing Luke, with the entrance in the background.]

It had previously been [Anakin's SECOND lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_second_lightsaber).

[image: Publicity still of Anakin from "Revenge of the Sith." Anakin stands in Jedi robes facing the viewer, holding his lightsaber vertically in a two-handed grip in front of his right shoulder. His left hand is on the hilt at waist level, his gloved right hand above it.]

Obi-Wan picked it up after dismembering Anakin in Episode III.

[image: Frame from "Revenge of the Sith" showing Obi-Wan's boot and left hand as he reaches down to pick up the lightsaber]

He held onto it for years, and gave it to Luke in Episode IV.

[image: Frame from "A New Hope" in Obi-Wan's home. Obi-Wan, right of frame, shows the lightsaber to Luke, centre frame facing the viewer. C-3PO sits at the left side, observing.]

Luke carried it until his hand was chopped off by Vader in Cloud City in Episode V.

[image: Frame from "The Empire Strikes Back;" Luke, right of frame facing left, recoils, head back, eyes shut and crying out, as his severed hand flies away still holding his lightsaber.]

[The hand, still clutching the lightsaber, can be seen falling from Cloud City near the end of Episode V](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-that-lukes-hand-falling-down-at-the-end-of-the-empire-strikes-back).

[image: Frame from "The Empire Strikes Back" looking down along the length of the reactor stalk. Luke's hand is just barely visible as it drops toward the clouds below.]

At some point, someone obviously recovered the lightsaber, although we don't know who found it or what the circumstances were.  Some time later, the lightsaber somehow came into Maz Kanata's possession, and in *The Force Awakens*, Rey discovers it - and ultimately takes possession of it, at least for the time being.

[image: Still from "The Force Awakens;" Maz Kanata's hand, reaching into the frame from the lower right, holds Luke's lightsaber out to Rey, left of frame, whose arm and hand are extended to accept it.]

Finn uses this lightsaber in his fight with the stormtrooper.

[image: Still from "The Force Awakens." Finn, facing forward and left from the right side of the frame, holds the lightsaber in the middle of the frame, with Maz Kanata, standing in front of some ruined structure, looking on from the left.]

Both Finn and Rey use it in their fight with Kylo Ren.

[image: Frame from "The Force Awakens" with Finn standing in a snowy night-dark forest, face illuminated by the blade of the lightsaber, which he holds in a two-handed sideways stance facing the viewer]
[image: Close up of a frame from "The Force Awakens" with Rey standing in a snowy dark forest, illuminated from the right, holding the lightsaber in her right hand.]

#### The green lightsaber:

After Luke lost his first lightsaber, he needed to replace it (what good is a Jedi with no lightsaber?), so he built a new one;  this lightsaber has a green blade.

*Deleted scene from Episode VI, in which Luke constructs his second lightsaber*

He uses this, [his second lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker%27s_lightsaber), in Episode VI.

[image: Still from "Return of the Jedi" with Luke in his black robes facing the viewer with his green lightsaber in a two-handed grip ahead of his body pointed slightly left. The "sail" of Jabba's barge is above him, the rail and deck behind him and the horizon of Tatooine - light sand below, washed out blue sky above - are in the background]

As the previous answers have said, Luke's first and second lightsabers are not merely different colors;  the hilts of the two lightsabers look nothing alike.

[image: Prop photo of Luke's first (blue) lightsaber]
*Luke's first lightsaber/Anakin's second lightsaber/the lightsaber Rey and Finn use/the blue lightsaber*

[image: Prop photo of Luke's second (green) lightsaber]
*Luke's second lightsaber/the green lightsaber*

The reason the hilts are so different is because Luke's first lightsaber was made by Anakin, to Anakin's personal specifications, whereas Luke seems to have modeled his second lightsaber on [Obi-Wan's third and final lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_third_lightsaber).

[image: Prop photo of Obi-Wan's third lightsaber]
*Obi-Wan's third lightsaber*

[image: Still from "A New Hope" of Vader dueling Obi-Wan. Vader is standing left of center, facing away from the viewer, who looks over Vader's right shoulder. Vader's red lightsaber is pointing towards Obi-Wan, who is blocking it with his blue one. Obi-Wan is facing the viewer, the cowl of his robe partially pushed back, holding his lightsaber two-handed. Behind Obi-Wan an illuminated panel relieves the solid grey walls.]
*Obi-Wan using his third lightsaber in his final duel with Vader*

### Why are they different colors?

A lightsaber's color doesn't affect its performance, and is a reflection of the color of [crystal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal) used to build it.  Anakin built his second lightsaber with a blue crystal, so the blade was blue;  obviously, it remained blue after Luke started using it.

[When Luke built his second lightsaber](http://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker%27s_green_lightsaber#Description), he used a green [kyber crystal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal), presumably because it was the only one available to him;  in any case, there was no reason for him to *not* use a green crystal - as I said, the color doesn't alter the weapon's performance.

The only real significance behind lightsaber colors in the *Star Wars* movies is that red lightsabers are almost exclusively wielded by the bad guys.  Most Jedi in the movies carry blue or green lightsabers, although [Mace Windu had a purple lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mace_Windu%27s_lightsaber), and yellow lightsabers have been used by Jedi elsewhere.

Comment: this answer looks [familiar](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111600/54827) ... lol

Comment: Can't fool me, that's totally a sonic screwdriver.

Comment: Actually, according to the new canon the color is a reflection of various attributes of the owner.

Comment: Great answer. Out-of-universe, it was originally intended that all Jedi use blue lightsabers and all Sith use red ones; but then *Return of the Jedi* came along, and they discovered that Luke's blue lightsaber was [awfully hard to see](https://www.cbr.com/star-wars-luke-green-lightsaber/) against the blue sky. So it was switched to green, which spawned a much broader lightsaber spectrum.

Answer (score 6):

## Because it was Anakin's lightsaber

If you look at the picture in the other answer, you can see that the one given to Rey matches the one given to Luke in *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*.

To compare to [Luke’s green lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker%27s_lightsaber):

[image: Prop image of the green lightsaber that Luke constructed for himself after losing the one given to him by Obi-Wan]

As you can see, it looks *nothing* like the one from *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope* or *Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens*.

Answer (score 2):

That is Luke's lightsaber, as Obi-Wan gave him his father's lightsaber, which he took after the fight he had with Anakin. In Episode VI, he had a new lightsaber, which is green, as already been pointed out he needed another lightsaber. So the crystal he got was green instead of blue. Originally his lightsaber in Episode VI was supposed to be blue, as seen in the original trailer, but was changed as it's said it was difficult to see with the blue sky for Tatooine.

But either way, the first lightsaber Luke got was his. It was given to him. And also, if Anakin did actually die, I'm sure he'd want his son to have his lightsaber. It would be like a family heirloom.

Comment: Welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. Great first answer; even though most answers have the basic facts, yours has the teaser trailer with the blue blade. (Have you taken the [tour] yet?}

Answer (score -1):

So everybody here, unfortunately, is incorrect.  If you compare the digital remake of the original films to the 35 millimeter film version, you will see that Luke's first lightsaber from Ben is more green than it is blue.

Check out [this guy's side-by-side comparisons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXouI.jpg) for an idea.

You could probably hedge and say "it's SORT of blue", but I think it's pretty clearly on the greener hue, myself.  ...and you can obviously see that they blue'd it up for the digital remake.

[image: comparison of Luke's light saber]

Comment: The originals didn't add color until ROTJ.  They were white.  Any perceived color may have been inadvertently added as part of post production scene coloring.

Comment: @gregsdennis Vader consistently went with red in ANH and the blue team went with blue. Marvel comics from that time confirm.

Answer (score -2):

Lucas said the only reason they made Luke's green in Return of the Jedi, was because the blue didn't show up well in the fight on Jabba's barge. So really, they both were initially intended to be blue.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this?

Comment: Agreed, where did Lucas say this?

Answer (score -4):

There is a color called cryn which resembles what people are calling ice. It has been proven that the color change (green) although seen and explained in comics was attributed to blue not showing up well in the landscape (outside).